# Autoforms and inheritance in MDriven

Tags: mdriven

I am using autoforms and have made an object model where one (superclass) has two subclasses. When navigating to this class using autoforms I would assume that the autoform only would show "forms/VM" for creating the subclasses, not the superclass as it is abstract. 
1) Classes that are abstract shouldn't be creatable? 
2) "autoform navigation" towards an abstract class should redirect to the sub-classes?

Or is there a setting for this? Has anyone experienced this?

Update: I do get an error  when an abstract class is created....but shouldn't autoforms skip to the subclases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Class you have an AutoForms setting.
The possible values are:

- Skip
- DocumentOnly
- SeekerOnly
- DocumentAndSeeker
- ValueStorePattern

If you set AutoForms to Skip on the SuperClass you get the effect you seek.
I do agree with you - abstract classes should really default to Skip on this setting.

Comment: Aha. I was wondering what the AutoForm attribute on the class did.